# Type of extremum in Lagrange Multiplier Method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Let's say I'm given that there are rectangular boxes all of which have a constant surface area, say **S**. Now, I want to find the box with either the maximum volume or the minimum volume.

If I apply Lagrange Multiplier Method and solve the set of equations, I'll get a solution. But how do I know whether it is for the maximum volume or minimum volume?

Is there a way to say what type of extremum we get after applying Lagrange Method, if we don't already know the type of extremum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum is obviously the degenerate case some-lenght = 0. The maximum obviously exists (why?). What can be your solution?

Comment: Is it always true that we get a minimum by equating one parameter to 0? I'm not necessarily talking about that box problem here.

Comment: Isn't. Compare the cases of $xyz$  and $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)$.